# How to display latest data in popup

Tags: popup, android-room, dao, android-livedata

I am developing a simple golf scoring app as a learning exercise for android devices.  After the score for a hole is entered I want to display the progress score as a popup over the main display which displays the results for each hole in a recyclerview.  The data in the recycler view updates as expected but, when the popup shows, the totals are one hole behind.  It appears as if, perhaps, the queries for summations from the database are being done before the database update with the new score is complete.

I have read the Android developers sections on room and searched widely for similar problems and worked through a number of tutorials but nothing seems to match this situation.  I have seen a suggestion that running the queries as transactions might help but my efforts at that have made no difference.

In the Dao there are a number of the following type of query

```java
@Transaction
    @Query("SELECT SUM(strokes) AS frontstrokes FROM score_table WHERE hole <= 9")
    LiveData<Integer> getStrokesFront();
```

In the ViewModel the corresponding code is

```java
public LiveData<Integer> getStrokesFront(){return strokesFront;}
```

The Repository contains

```java
public LiveData<Integer> getStrokesFront() {
        return strokesFront;
    }
```

In MainActivity inside the onCreate we have

```java
scoringViewModel.getStrokesFront().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                frontstrokes = integer;
            }
        });
```

Inside onActivityResult we have (after return from the score entry activity)

```java
 scoringViewModel.update(scoring);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Score added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            loadData();

            showProgress();
```

And in showProgress we have

```java
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoring_header, null);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.comp_name)).setText(comp);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.strokes_value)).setText(String.format("%d", frontstrokes));
```

The reason that I think it is a 'timing' thing is that if I return to the score entry activity and make no changes but press the save again, the update of the totals is now correct.

The following does appear in the Logcat

```
2019-06-05 14:30:13.906 31492-31492/org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp.MainActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{3e7185f V.E...... R....... 0,0-800,570} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:627)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:377)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1573)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1339)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:1305)
        at org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp.MainActivity$override.showProgress(MainActivity.java:297)
        at org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp.MainActivity$override.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:208)
        at org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:92)
        at org.ivanhoegc.ivanhoegolfscoringapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:39)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8006)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4638)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4687)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

EDIT:
I have been doing some poking around with debug.

Here is the code for my pop-up.

```java
private void showProgress(){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoring_header, null);

        float density = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, (int)density * 400, (int)density * 285,true);
        pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));


        scoringViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ScoringViewModel.class);

        scoringViewModel.getStrokesFront().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                frontstrokes = integer;
            }
        });
        scoringViewModel.getPointsFront().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                frontpoints = integer;
            }
        });
        scoringViewModel.getStrokesBack().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                backstrokes = integer;
            }
        });
        scoringViewModel.getPointsBack().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                backpoints = integer;
            }
        });
        scoringViewModel.getStrokesTotal().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                totalstrokes = integer;
            }
        });
        scoringViewModel.getPointsTotal().observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
                totalpoints = integer;
            }
        });

        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.comp_name)).setText(comp);
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.strokes_value)).setText(String.format("%d", frontstrokes));
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.points_value)).setText(String.format("%d", frontpoints));
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bstrokes_value)).setText(String.format("%d", backstrokes));
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.bpoints_value)).setText(String.format("%d", backpoints));
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rstrokes_value)).setText(String.format("%d", totalstrokes));
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rpoints_value)).setText(String.format("%d", totalpoints));

        pw.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
                    pw.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

Looking at the values that I want to display, they are not updated until after the pop-up is displayed.  This is despite the new individual score and points values being clearly displayed in the recycler view beneath the pop-up.  A break at the setTouchInterceptor shows the old values while a break at the action check 'if statement' reveals the new values.  Rearranging the order of the prior code has no effect on the result.

Any ideas please?

Comment: did you try to update your popup inside livedata observer

Comment: @skyshine That sounds like an idea but as a learner I'm not exactly sure how that would be implemented.  Could you give a hint as to the code required?